# How do I pass an objects method as parameter without the object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, parameter-passing

So, I've got a situation where i need to call a method of my object, but at the time I'm calling it, both the object and the method being called may vary.

```
var myCallback = "nameOfMethod"; //this can change throughout

function myObj(){
    this.method1 = function(){//code};
    this.method2 = function(){//more code};
}

var o1 = new myObj();
var o2 = new myObj();

//this is what i'm not sure how to do, but effectively...
//where myCallback could be method1 or method2
//and someObject could be o1 or o2 (for example)

doSomething(someObject,myCallback);

function doSomething(anObj, aMethod){
    anObj.aMethod();
    //or this
    aMethod.call(anObj);
}
```

EDIT:
 OKay. to clarify the issue. inside method1 and method2 it refers to other properties of the object using `this` i.e. this.myProperty ...but when i call the method using `anObj[aMethod]()` in doSomething, it returns this.myProperty as undefined...

if my object was as follows, for example:

```
function myObj(){
    this.myProperty = "value";
    this.method1 = function(){
        console.log(this.myProperty);
    };
    this.method2 = function(){/* more code */};
}

var o1 = new myObj();
var o2 = new myObj();

//this is what i'm not sure how to do, but effectively...
//where myCallback could be method1 or method2
//and someObject could be o1 or o2 (for example)

doSomething(someObject,myCallback);

function doSomething(anObj, aMethod){
    anObj[aMethod]();
}
```

Comment: oops. as I made my changes...that does work...man, I'm striking out here. Ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to make the call is

```
anObj[aMethod]();
```

Your problem is that `aMethod` is a the name of a property and not a function in itself. `anObj[aMethod]` converts the name to a function by reading a property of the object.

That said, it's not very common in JavaScript to pass a callback around as two separate values when you can simply pass a function directly.

Comment: `anObj[aMethod]()` will work just fine too.  `.call()` is only needed if you want to pass a different object than the one you're referencing the method on.

Comment: @jfriend00: `.call` cannot be any worse, but it can be better depending on what the methods do exactly.

Comment: `.call()` just isn't needed here.  It's extra cruft/complication not needed in the solution.  I was suggesting an improvement/simplification to your answer.

Comment: It's not "more correct" in any way.  No function/method call ever needs `.call()` unless you want to pass a custom object to it.  `obj[method]()` works just fine.  `obj[method]()` will automatically set `obj` as the `this` pointer in the method call.

Comment: Apologies for being dense. It's late around here; that's my excuse and I 'm sticking with it. Answer edited.

Comment: @Jon - +1, no apology needed, I got completely confused from the poor indenting of the code in the question, it happens all the time (at least for me ?).